# Como fazer um autorelacionamento M:N no Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Boa tarde, 
Preciso fazer um autorelacionamento e estou bem confusa como devo fazer isso. 
Em meu sistema eu tenho diversas variáveis de processo, uma mesma variável de processo pode ser Pai de diversas outras variáveis, mas essa mesma variável também pode ser filha de outras variáveis. 
Vi algumas maneiras de fazer autorelacionamento, mas nenhuma delas pareceu "certa" pro meu caso.

```
public class VariavelProcesso
{
 public int VariavelProcessoId { get; set; }

 public int? VariavelPaiId { get; set; }
 public virtual VariavelProcesso VariavelPai { get; set; }
 public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: O título diz uma coisa e o texto diz outra.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Qual a versão do EntityFramework está utilizando? Utilizando .Net Framework ou já é .Net Core?

Considerando o uso do EF Core 2.x ou superior

```
public class VariavelProcesso
{
    public int VariavelProcessoId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentVariavelProcessoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual VariavelProcesso Pai { get; set; }
    public virtual HashSet<VariavelProcesso> Filho { get; set; }   
}

//Fluente API

modelBuilder.Entity<VariavelProcesso>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Pai)
    .WithMany(x => x.Filho)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.VariavelProcessoId);
```